# Which model of MBT desoldering station is this?

Tags: equipment

From [Commodore 128 Complete Restoration and Board Repair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLp6bzG9exk) @ [11:55](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLp6bzG9exk&t=715), Raymond, the chap doing the desoldering, appears to be using one of these:

[image: MBT desoldering station]

There is, however, no model number on the front.

From an ancient eBay item description, I found one (and the image above) described as a Pace MBT 250, but the MBT250 has a digital front end, so that can't be right.

Does anyone know, or is familiar with, this desoldering station and know the model number?

---

Note: For full disclosure, I have previously looked into this in 2019 and suspected that it *might* be a PPS80A (aka MBT201) - which I made a note about about on [my blog](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2019/11/08/solder-sucker/).

Comment: I have one of those! Bought it back in the late 90’s. Still ticking although I’ve had to fix the pump.

Comment: Yes, they do seem to be really rather reliable, by all accounts. That's why I'm trying to find one. However, some (the units from the US) seem to be 110V only... 240V versions *are* available, but you need to check the label on the back, to see if they have that capability first.

Comment: Generally reliable, but by now there’s a fair chance the iron has been replaced and probably the desoldering tool. If the originals fail, they are obsolete, so you need to buy a new iron etc. the pump rubbers deteriorate and the plastic pump crank fails due to stress. I can’t really complain though as I worked it hard for a few years. Nowadays the soldering iron is average compared to the likes of JBC and Metcal. The desoldering tool is still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a Pace MBT PPS80A. Here is a link to the [Pace Service Manual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://paceworldwide.com/sites/default/files/2019-07/MBT-201_Service-Manual.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiduL3Jm-j9AhUchf0HHZ3iAAAQFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw28Yfyi8yhv92gV-ghxVWvA).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had suspected as much (and forgot to mention it). Page 5 shows it as a PPS80A/MBT201.